# Laravel update a column to a specific value for ALL users

Tags: laravel

What's the most efficient way to update a column to all users at once?

```
$allUsers = Users::All();
```

Do I need to `foreach` every user or there is any eloquent command I can do this with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this also

```
DB::table('Users')->update(['column' => 'value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `update()` with `where()`:

```
Users::where('id', '<>', 0)->update(['column' => 'new value']);
```

I've tested it, this will work only with `where()`, if you'll try to use just `update()`, you'll get an error.

Comment: I am sure the update command doesn't return $allUsers. So, `$allUsers = Users::get();` should come in the next line.